# How to make a div fixed while scrolling

Tags: jquery, css

Is there a way using JQuery that i can detect when a div starts going offscreen , and change its CSS so that its position changes to fixed and is stuck to the bottom of the window ?

Comment: `position:fixed;bottom:10px;` in `css` by using `jQuery` will help you

Comment: Voting to close for not providing any code or showing any research effort whatsoever.

Comment: There are already many threads on stick footers.  Look for those.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you are looking for is Sticky Elements in JQuery with waypoints if I'm correct. Take a look at this page: [JQuery Waypoints](http://imakewebthings.com/jquery-waypoints/)

Comment: Overkill for such a simple function.  See two previous answers.

Comment: I was posting reply before the other two questions popped up. I figured showing some info on an option rather than just giving code was more useful but thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: Posting a link instead of a complete, self-contained solution is the least desirable kind of answer on SO.

Answer (score 0):

CSS

```
.div-fixed {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 10px;
  right: 10px;
}
```

JS

```
if ($('#mydiv').offset().top() + $('#mydiv').height() > $(document).height()) {
  $('#mydiv').addClass('div-fixed');
}
```

Comment: I want to do this via JQuery . So that it is dyanmic

Answer (score 0):

Here's a **[jsFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/YYzVq/light/)** I've used before.

jQuery:

```
var stickerTop = parseInt($('#sticker').offset().top);
$(window).scroll(function() {
    $("#sticker").css((parseInt($(window).scrollTop()) + parseInt($("#sticker").css('margin-top')) > stickerTop) ? {
        position: 'fixed',
        top: '0px'
    } : {
        position: 'relative'
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

JS

```
var backup_position_toolbar = $('#toolbar').offset().top;
$(window).scroll(function() {
    if ( $('#toolbar').offset().top - $(window).scrollTop() < 0 ) $('#toolbar').addClass('fixed');
    if ( $(window).scrollTop() < backup_position_toolbar ) $('#toolbar').removeClass('fixed');
});
```

CSS

```
.fixed {
    margin: 1px;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
}
```